# Marklogic: Delete all element range indexes on a database?

Tags: marklogic

Is there an easy way to delete all the element range indexes on a given database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write some script to do this, for example in JavaScript which you need to execute from your Query Console:

```
'use strict';

const admin = require('/MarkLogic/admin');
const config = admin.getConfiguration();
const db = xdmp.database('Documents');

const indexes = admin.databaseGetRangeElementIndexes(config, db);
const newConfig = admin.databaseDeleteRangeElementIndex(config, db, indexes);
admin.saveConfiguration(newConfig);

'All Range Indexes have been removed.'
```

The above goes through all the Element Range Indexes for the 'Documents' database and removes them - including any pre-defined Range Indexes for DLS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this using the REST Management API method `PUT /manage/v2/databases/{dbid}/properties`. If you pass a payload in which the `range-element-indexes` property is empty, I think it removes any existing ones.

Take a look at the following:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties

You'd want to use a payload similar to the following for XML:

```
<database-properties xmlns="http://marklogic.com/manage">
<range-element-indexes/>
</database-properties>
```

Or like this for JSON:

```
{ "range-element-index": [] }
```

Be careful, though: It's a sharp tool. You'll also delete pre-defined indexes like the ones for DLS. I think that's also true of Tamas' solution, but did not confirm.

Comment: P.S. That's not a typo in the property name: It is plural in XML and singular is JSON.

Comment: Always try the Manage API when possible (and it will certainly work here). It doesn't require a user with the "admin" role but rather the more limited "manage-admin" role, and you can get things done via your favorite HTTP client.